# Task completion condition

Tags: workflow

I am trying to change the completion condition so that the process ends when 50% of the workflow participants approve it. My idea is to stop the process as soon as 50% of the approvers approve the task. I have change the conditions as seen in the image below.

However, the task process is **waiting** for all participants to vote, then it moves to the next step and do the percentage calculation.

Any idea to finish the process by reaching 50% of approvals, no matter how many participants still haven't voted?

Thank you again.

[image]

Comment: What version of workflow is it (2010/2013)?

Comment: If you are using SP 2013 WF, use the Start a task and configure the completion logic for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with those first two conditions:

"If future task count equals 0" means "if all tasks in the process have been created"

"If active task count equals 0" means "if there are no more tasks waiting for a response"

Try removing those two conditions.

Comment: If I remove the first two conditions, after the first approver vote "Approve" the system checks if the percentage of approved is greater than 50%. Since only one person voted "Approve" (less than 50%), the system sets to Rejected.

Comment: You'll have to play around with the conditions, but this is where your problem is. E.g. try moving the last two activities into the IF statement so that everything is under the IF.